# maven platform encoding

Tags: maven

when you run `mvn --version` part of the output includes the locale and pratform encoding.
For example: `Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252`

I would like to know where it picks these up from and how they can be set

Answer (score 41):

maven picking these values from Java system properties. Here is how you could set encoding:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Or:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Or pass parameter to maven command line:

```
mvn -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: The best thing is to put such kind of information into the pom or into a company pom NEVER on command line.

Comment: It works in a pom.xml, but it doesn't answer the question of a global configuration for mvn --version

Comment: this first answer has 2 faults: it lacks setting project.reporting.outputEncoding, and even with that, it works for one pom only. If you have a serious project, you have to put those settings into POM in every module. The sensible global solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976788/715269. The second answer is even worse. The last one is acceptable for work in Eclipse. So, it is not universal because of inconvenience.

Comment: If you give several answers, you should say in what case we should use which.

Answer (score 33):

You could set environment information for maven (on a windows system) with

```
set "MAVEN_OPTS=-Duser.language=fr -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: @cdog, it would be nice if you mark this post as an answer so others would see it right away.

Comment: +1. Excellent. That is the only way to set the coding for all maven globally. Or we should create POM in every project and put two properties into every one - obvious nonsense.

Answer (score 11):

```
set MAVEN_OPTS= -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

Actually it won't work, you need to remove the quotes ("") :

```
set MAVEN_OPTS= -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: a least on cygwin you have to replace set with export & the value has to be quoted like : `export MAVEN_OPTS=" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    ...
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

More:
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/11/special-character-encoding-properties/

Comment: That's exactly, what I do
https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/pmd-java-14/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The only thing that works is to set the 
appropriate MAVEN_OPTS. So if you use windows you can adapt mvn.bat 
in %MAVEN_HOME%/bin as follows:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=%MAVEN_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

Following this mvn -v shows this:

```
..
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
..
```