# How to verify used encoding in sourcefiles using checkstyle-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, checkstyle

Simple thing: I want to be able to break builds via checkstyle, if selected files (`.java`, `.xml`) are not encoded properly (I want to enforce `UTF-8` in source files).

I'm currently using checkstyle for a number of other build-breakers, like enforcing correct LineFeeds and/or usage of Tab Characters, but there does not seem to be something like a `FileEncodingChecker`.

**Question**: If checkstyle simply can't do this: is there another plugin that might do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven encoding (sources and resources) is handled by the standard `project.build.sourceEncoding` property, which indeed should be present and set to the `UTF-8` value, as a good practice.
From official documentation of the [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html)

> The best practice is to define encoding for copying filtered resources via the property `${project.build.sourceEncoding}` which should be defined in the pom properties section

This property is picked up as default value of the [`encoding`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding) property of the `maven-compiler-plugin` and the [`encoding`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#encoding) property of the `maven-resources-plugin`.

---

To further enforce its presence, you could then use the [`maven-enforcer-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) and its [`requireProperty`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) rule, in order to enforce the existence of the `project.build.sourceEncoding` property and its value at `UTF-8`. That is, the build would fail if the property was not set AND did not have this exact value.

Below an example of such a configuration, to add to your `pom.xml` file, `build/plugins` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-property</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <requireProperty>
                        <property>project.build.sourceEncoding</property>
                        <message>Encoding must be set and at UTF-8!</message>
                        <regex>UTF-8</regex>
                        <regexMessage>Encoding must be set and at UTF-8</regexMessage>
                    </requireProperty>
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

Note, the same could be done for the `project.reporting.outputEncoding` property.

---

Further reading on Stack Overflow:

- [How to configure encoding in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven)
- [Maven platform encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976616/maven-platform-encoding)
- [Maven: Source Encoding in UTF-8 not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656475/maven-source-encoding-in-utf-8-not-working)

---

*Bonus*: since we are on Stack Overflow, the CEO would probably be happy to see his old article back again: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

---

**Test**
Given the following Java code:

```
package com.sample;

public class Main {

    public void 漢字() {
    }

}
```

and setting the following in Maven:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>US-ASCII</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Would actually make the build fail, since `US-ASCII` is 7 bits and woudl result in illegal character errors. The same would not happen for `UTF-8`, which makes uses of 8 bits instead.

Comment: @a-di-matteo: Thanks for this extensive answer, works perfectly for me. I'm still feeling a bit unhappy about using two plugins for achieving some (IMHO) simple build breaking scenario.

Comment: I am tried replacing regex/properties with `ISO-8859-1` also added plugin in root pom. As i want to enforce this encoding on my project, it didn't work. I am having multi-module project, am i missing something