# jsp:param encoding problems

Tags: java, jsp

So I have several .jsp files:

one of the files has the head tag and has the title of the page:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>${param.title}</title>
</head>
```

The other files include the first one and pass to it a param using jsp:param:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:include page="consoleheader.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="title" value="Título"/>
</jsp:include>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Any non-ASCII characters that I pass using jsp:param are getting garbled when I do this (the í in Título for instance). Everywhere else it works fine.
All jsp files are encoded using UTF-8. I have not set any charset configurations on my JVM. Anyone knows how to fix this without setting the JVM encoding by hand?

Comment: how do you package your WAR? maven?

Comment: @YevgeniyM. I have an ant script that does the work. Why?

Comment: i recall similar problems when using filtering without encoding being set in pom.xml

Comment: @YevgeniyM. I do am using filters.

Comment: this answer would help, if it was maven: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSTL worked here. It's more verbose though:

"head":

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>${title}</title>
</head>
```

"body":

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="title" scope="request" value="Título"/>
<jsp:include page="consoleheader.jsp">
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with jsp params and hacked it in the following way:

main.jsp:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head/>
  <body>
    <jsp:include page="other.jsp">
      <%-- í = &iacute; --%>
      <jsp:param name="title" value="T&iacute;tulo"/>
    </jsp:include>
  </body>
</html>
```

other.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<h1><c:out value="${param.title}" escapeXml="false"/></h1>
```

---

I know it is not the best solution, but it worked for me.

---

#### Edit

I found an [other solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omaha-java-users-group/SBVal1wEj98) that is could work for you too:

> Adding the setCharacterEncoding line below before the jsp:include does the trick.
> `<% request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); %>`

Comment: This solution worked for me (From your EDIT). Weird. Honestly, i don't like using this before an include.. its somewhat counter-productive.

Answer (score 1):

Could the param value be dinamic? . If not, replace "í" for

`&#237;`

Comment: Well this is hardly ideal, but it no other solution presents itself I can live with this