# Textfield Arabic output shows strange characters javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm working on a desktop application using javaFX, I'm using scene builder version 11 to create my interface that contains TextFields and ChoiceBox, my inputs are supposed to be set **in Arabic**. The problem is when I retrieve the text from the TextFiled or the ChoiceBox and print it in the console it shows characters like that "Ø¨Ù†Ù†Ù„Ù†Ù„Ù†" and it also generates a problem to store the inputs in database, this is the SQLException:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Ø¨Ù†Ù†Ù„Ù†Ù„Ù†,Ù†Ø¨Ù„Ù†Ø¨Ù†Ù„Ø¨,2021-06-30,Ø£Ù…Ø± Ø¬Ø²Ø§Ø¦ÙŠ,ØªÙ… Ø§Ù„ØªØ¨Ù„ÙŠØº

When I tried another project without scene builder I got the Arabic outputs correctly, could scene bulider be the problem's origin?

here is my fxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorIns" prefHeight="529.0" prefWidth="523.0" stylesheets="@newinsc.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="newInsc.NewInscController">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="boxContainer" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="273.0" prefWidth="245.0">
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="245.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="firstNameTxtField" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="71.0" stylesheets="@newinsc.css" text="الاسم" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="245.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="lastNameTxtField" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" />
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="اللقب" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="245.0">
               <children>
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="docTypeChoice" prefWidth="150.0" />
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="نوع التبليغ" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="245.0">
               <children>
                  <DatePicker fx:id="dateField" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="التاريخ" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="245.0">
               <children>
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="tablighCase" prefWidth="150.0" />
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="71.0" text="حالة التبليغ" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#cancelBtnClicked" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="245.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="cancleBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#cancelBtnClicked" text="الغاء">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="16.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="saveInscBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#registerBtnClicked" text="تسجيل" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and this here is my controller file:

```
package newInsc;

import DB.dbConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author asus
 */
public class NewInscController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> docTypeChoice;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> tablighCase;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker dateField;
    @FXML
    private Button saveInscBtn;
    @FXML
    private TextField firstNameTxtField;
    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameTxtField;
    @FXML
    private Button cancleBtn;
    
    private Connection c;
    private Statement s;
    @FXML
    private VBox boxContainer;

 
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

     docTypeChoice.getItems().add("أمر جزائي");
     docTypeChoice.getItems().add("حكم جزائي" );
     docTypeChoice.getItems().add("تكليف بالحضور" );
     docTypeChoice.getItems().add("قرار جزائي" );
     
     tablighCase.getItems().add("تم التبليغ");
     tablighCase.getItems().add("ترك اشعار");
     tablighCase.getItems().add("عدم التمكن من التبليغ");
     
     
    }    

    @FXML
    private void cancelBtnClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        Stage s = (Stage) cancleBtn.getScene().getWindow();
        
    }

    @FXML
    private void registerBtnClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        try {
            String query;
            String fname = firstNameTxtField.getText();
            String lname = lastNameTxtField.getText();
            LocalDate date = dateField.getValue();
            String docType = docTypeChoice.getValue();
            String state = tablighCase.getValue();
           
            query = "insert into infotable values " + fname + "," +  lname + ","  + date+ ","+ docType+"," +state ;
            dbConnection dbc = new dbConnection();
            s = dbc.createConnection().createStatement();
            s.execute(query);
            s.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewInscController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }


    
}
```

Comment: This could be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/q/14091011/6708879. Basically what you are experiencing is the wonderfull world of character encoding. This tutorial could also be of help: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-encode-utf-8. I don't know where you are coding but look also at the character encoding of the IDE. Eclipse uses cp1252 in window by default

Comment: @MissingSemiColon thanks for your answer, I use netbeans IDE, actually the used encoding in my fxml file is UTF-8 but I don't understand why the output coming from a textfield or choicebox isn't displayed in Arbaic letter.

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution, before I run the program I **first** compile it with **F9 key** then I run it with a **key combination SHIFT + F6**