# How can I build maven project with foreign class names?

Tags: java, maven

I'am trying to build war file for my project, that is containing russian class names. When I just run my app on development environment, it works good, but if I build that war file, all russian filenames are mangled. I cannot rename these files in the project so they could be in english. The only way out is to make my own refactoring utility for them, and run it every time these files are regenerated.
So I want to know if there is a way to make maven build it with locale specific configuration.
These files are having proper names while theq are on my filesystem. But theqy are changed when I look at them in war archive.

pom.xml snippet

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: "mangled". How? What exatly is the problem?

Comment: file name characters are changed into question marks.

Comment: 1) Post the relevant parts of your `pom.xml`. 2) Check the encoding of every file involved.

Comment: Seems like these files in utf8. If it was a problem I think they would havebad names even in developement environment/

Comment: I build the project with eclipse if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should always fix the encoding of source files:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Also read the http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning and [How to configure encoding in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven) for additional information.