# Spring Rest Docs. Invalid UTF-8 middle byte while snippets generation

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, code-snippets, asciidoctor

Please help me with an issue I have while using Spring Rest docs. 
I have made all required setting from Spring manual.
I wrote Spring MVC Test. Here is the code. Strange symbols are in Russian.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@Slf4j
public class ProductApiControllerTest {

    protected static final long TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1 = 11_071_076_993L;
    protected static final long TEST_PRODUCT_ID_2 = 21_071_076_994L;

    public static final Product TEST_PRODUCT_1 = Product.builder()
            .id(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1)
            .productId(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1)
            .name("WRX3000")
            .fullName("WRX3000")
            .regionPickupAvailable(Arrays.asList("a100"))
            .regionDeliveryAvailable(Arrays.asList("b200"))
            .categoryId(100500)
            .categoryName("Телевизоры")
            .categories(Arrays.asList(10L, 20L, 30L))
            .brandId(200300)
            .brandName("Samsung")
            .description("AMOLED HD Телевизор 4 поколения")
            .prices(Arrays.asList(Price.builder().baseStore("b200").priceId(777).priceValue(2990d).oldPriceValue(3490d).build()))
            .build();

    @Mock
    private SearchService searchServiceMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private ProductApiController controller;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private RestDocumentationResultHandler document;


    @Rule
    public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.document = document("{method-name}", preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()));
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation).snippets().withEncoding("UTF-8"))
                .alwaysDo(document)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetProduct() throws Exception {
        log.info("Test getProduct(..) from ProductApiController");
        when(searchServiceMock.findByProductId(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1, "b200")).thenReturn(TEST_PRODUCT_1);
        this.document.snippets(responseFields(
                fieldWithPath("id").description("Идентификатор для служебных целей поисковой машины."),
                fieldWithPath("name").description("Название продукта"),
                fieldWithPath("fullName").description("Полное название продукта"),
                fieldWithPath("productId").description("Идентификатор (SKU) товара"),
                fieldWithPath("regionPickupAvailable").description("Показывает доступен ли продукт для самовывоза в данном регионе"),
                fieldWithPath("regionDeliveryAvailable").description("Показывает доступен ли продукт для доставки в данном регионе"),
                fieldWithPath("categoryId").description("Идентификатор категории, к которой принадлежит товар"),
                fieldWithPath("categoryName").description("Название категории, к которой принадлежит товар"),
                fieldWithPath("categories").description("Список идентификаторов категорий к которым принадлежит товар"),
                fieldWithPath("brandId").description("Идентификатор бренда товара"),
                fieldWithPath("brandName").description("Название бренда продукта"),
                fieldWithPath("description").description("Описание товара"),
                fieldWithPath("propertyAggregate").description("Какая-то фигня"),
                fieldWithPath("propepropertyAggregatertyMap").description("Дополнительные свойства товара"),
                fieldWithPath("price").description("Цена товара"),
                fieldWithPath("oldPrice").description("Предыдущая цена товара")
        ));
        mockMvc.perform(get(Constants.RestApiV1.ROOT_PATH + "/" + Constants.RestApiV1.GET_PRODUCTS + "/" + TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1 + "?baseStore=b200").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productId").value(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("WRX3000"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.fullName").value("WRX3000"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.regionPickupAvailable").value(false)) // a100 != b200
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.regionDeliveryAvailable").value(true)) // b200 == b200
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.categoryId").value(100500))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.brandName").value("Samsung"));
    }
}
```

The problem is when I start this test from IDE (Intellij IDEA) it works fine and produces all snippets. But when I run maven "package" task test fails with 
Results :

```
Tests in error: 
  testGetProduct(ru.eldorado.searchservice.web.controllers.rest.ProductApiControllerTest): com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe5
```

I have checked the problem is in fields description. If I delete this part package goal executes fine.

Encoding of my project and all the output files is UTF-8. In maven I explicitly specified

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

Any help and ideas will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: But, is `ProductApiControllerTest.java` *actually* saved in UTF-8? In Eclipse, you can have different encoding for any file, and Eclipse knows and compiles ok, but external compile would fail (or produce bad string literals) with mixed encodings. I don't know about Intellij, but could be same issue.

Comment: Yes, it is saved in UTF-8. Intellij shows it in bottom right side of the screen and I also checked project setting. It's UTF-8 everythere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other my answer is just a workaround. The real problem was in standard Windows encoding for Russian version(Cp-1251). Somehow maven parameters hadn't solved this issue. But environment variable

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

fixed everything. 
The answer have been found here [How to configure encoding in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28470840/4035262)

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question. 
The problem was in Russian characters here

```
 public static final Product TEST_PRODUCT_1 = Product.builder()
            .id(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1)
            .productId(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1)
            .name("WRX3000")
            .fullName("WRX3000")
            .regionPickupAvailable(Arrays.asList("a100"))
            .regionDeliveryAvailable(Arrays.asList("b200"))
            .categoryId(100500)
            .categoryName("Телевизоры")
            .categories(Arrays.asList(10L, 20L, 30L))
            .brandId(200300)
            .brandName("Samsung")
            .description("AMOLED HD Телевизор 4 поколения")
            .prices(Arrays.asList(Price.builder().baseStore("b200").priceId(777).priceValue(2990d).oldPriceValue(3490d).build()))
            .build();
```

I've added method

```
private static String getStringInUtf8(String source) {
    return new String(source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

and used it to assign values containing Russian characters in TEST_PRODUCT_1 declaration

```
public static final Product TEST_PRODUCT_1 = Product.builder()
        .id(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1)
        .productId(TEST_PRODUCT_ID_1)
        .name("WRX3000")
        .fullName("WRX3000")
        .regionPickupAvailable(Arrays.asList("a100"))
        .regionDeliveryAvailable(Arrays.asList("b200"))
        .categoryId(100500)
        .categoryName(getStringInUtf8("Телевизоры"))
        .categories(Arrays.asList(10L, 20L, 30L))
        .brandId(200300)
        .brandName("Samsung")
        .description(getStringInUtf8("Super AMOLED HD Телевизор 5 поколения"))
        .prices(Arrays.asList(Price.builder().baseStore("b200").priceId(777).priceValue(2990d).oldPriceValue(3490d).build()))
        .build();
```

It solved the problem but the root of it haven't been found.