# maven test fails at a eastern language character while IDEA success

Tags: java, maven

This is the test class:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@Sql(value = {"classpath:/ut_user_init.sql"})
public class UserControllerTest extends MockMvcTest {
    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = MockData.ADMIN_USERNAME, userDetailsServiceBeanName = "mockUserDetailsService")
    public void testGetUser() throws Exception {}
}
```

And the `UserController` class：

```
@RequestMapping("list")
public String list(Model model) {
   userService.findByName("[An Eastern character]")
}
```

And in `UserService` class:

```
User findByName(String name) {
     return userRepository.findByName(name); // name is in Eastern language.
}
```

This is related data in `ut_user_init.sql`

```
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('32', '[The Eastern character]');
```

This is effective `pom.xml`:

```
<maven.compiler.encoding>utf-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

Now the odd thing is: if I use IDEA the Service class returns a finding result, but if I use `mvn test -Dtest=path.to.TestClass`, it would fail because the return is null. But if I print the result of `userRepository.findAll().size()` I can see that it prints a correct number of records listed in sql file. And I also tried printing result of `userRepository.findOne(32L)`, in both MinGW (windows uses GDB for Eastern languages while the source files are in UTF-8) and Linux prints random code for the `name`. While IDEA does not have this problem, it returns the finding and it prints the Eastern Character as it is. Why mvn and IDEA behaves differently, and what caused mvn fail, and how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that when you run from the command line it is taking your system default encoding, which may not be UTF-8.

Try this:

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -Dtest=MyTestClassName
```

Comment: That works. But why mvn does not read pom.xml since the three properties are in utf-8 now. And why the pom.xml utf-8 configuration does not work? Are they used for different purpose, why pom.xml utf-8 configuration does not work?

Comment: Yes those POM properties are different from `file.encoding`. Just as extra information that may help you - there is a way to make `mvn test` do what you need, refer to this example (the `<systemProperties>` part): https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports