# False character generation in Maven ( "i" replaced with "ı")

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, encoding, character-encoding

I work in a Spring Boot/MVC project.After "mvn clean install "  first character of some method and package names which starts with "i" is replaced with "ı".For example "inquire"  becomes  "ınquıre" or "insurance" package becomes "ınsurance".I changed the default locale of maven to "en_US" and default encoding to "UTF-8" and set project encoding to "UTF-8" but still get the same errors.My windows 8 was installed in Turkish but I also changed keyboard settings to "English".

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you correctly configured you IDE to use UTF-8 for files and not the windows default ?

Comment: yes, I already set it @khmarbaise

Comment: does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28470840/2168752