# error: unmappable character (0x98) for encoding windows-1251

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, encoding, windows-1251

I have a problem with the assembly of the project:

> D:...\Main.java:112: error: unmappable character (0x98) for encoding
>   windows-1251
>   robot.getBrowserControl().findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='НАПИСАТЬ']")).click();

This error in line:
`robot.getBrowserControl().findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='НАПИСАТЬ']")).click();`

Images:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJjKq.png), [IDEA settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrN2W.png) . Ths bottom-right is selected UTF-8. I'm not sure, but maybe it's like the symbol "И"

[img errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AMDh.png)

This my gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'ru.grbi3yh.processthesefiles'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'ProcessthFiles'
}


apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.41.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.7'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming the element, so that it doesn't use special characters?

Comment: I would recommend you to not use cyrillic script in the naming of your variables/fields/anything really. You are kinda asking for encoding trouble this way.

Comment: Guys, that's not the element's name, that's the element's content.

Comment: I don't think I have the knowledge to help, but what are "robot" and "By.xpath()"? Sounds like they're demanding the XPath to be windows-1251 compatible, which is weird but might be configurable.

Comment: I tried to rename and copy the word "WRITE" from other texts.
This is not my cyrillic script. This is the "WRITE" button on google mail.

Comment: "robot" and "By.xpath()" in no way affect this error. In the class itself there is a comment of the developer and it has the symbol "И" there is also an error. Look at the image "error"

Comment: I see. From your screenshot I suppose you're using Maven. Maven will use the encoding set with Maven, not with Idea. Can you show your Maven configuration?

Comment: @kumesana i added gradle file watch

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of things that can be posted as (code formatted) text. Edit your question, and replace those screenshots with the actual text.

Comment: I honestly don't see a fault to it but then again I trust very little in gradle. I'd try to add `compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'`

Comment: @kumesana i add ` compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8' ` did not help

Comment: The problem is clearly that the compiler is using windows-1251 for java files, when by what you're saying they are encoded in utf-8. Maybe windows-1251 is the default encoding on your platform and that's why gradle is using it? Unfortunately I have no idea how to tell gradle what encoding to use for java files.

Comment: My platform Windows 10 and the default language is Russian

Comment: Something to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting encoding option for Java compilation should help:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

Comment: Could cmb tell where should I put these 2 lines?

Comment: in tasks section of your project's build.gradle.kts file:
tasks {
    compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative way to solve this error:

> "error: unmappable character (0x98) for encoding windows-1251"

you can also change the [default encoding](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007584839/comments/360001399139) inside `Custom VM Options...`:

[image]

by adding, e.g.:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Help | Edit Custom VM Options, then restart IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am too late for this problem (pretty sure yes) but my advise could help to other guys - the problem is in cyrillic symbols. I had the same problem and I solved that by saving the file using format ANSI (if you use use some text editor like notepad, you can save your fie in ANSI encoding. Perhaps this option should be in IDE)

Comment: This is not a solution to a problem, but humility.