# Unicode char are getting garbled when running with Maven

Tags: java, maven, unicode

**Unicode char are getting garbled when ruuning Maven**
When running the script as a Java program or using TestNG Unicode char is not garbled.
But I want to get it run with Maven.

Code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

    @Test
    void sample() {
        System.out.println("Hello how are you");
        System.out.println("乇乂丅尺卂 丅卄工匚匚 ｖａｐｏｒｗａｖｅ ォ威嵐");
    }

}
```

Maven version:

> PS F:\Java projects\Udemy_Selenium_Java> mvn --version
> Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0) Maven
> home: F:\Java projects\Dependencies\apache-maven-3.8.5 Java version:
> 17.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
> OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family:
> "windows"

Result when running with Maven and Unicode char garbled :

```
PS F:\Java projects\Udemy_Selenium_Java> mvn clean test -Dtest="TestClass"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.example:Udemy_Selenium_Java >-------------------
[INFO] Building Udemy_Selenium_Java 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Udemy_Selenium_Java ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Udemy_Selenium_Java ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Udemy_Selenium_Java ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 33 source files to F:\Java projects\Udemy_Selenium_Java\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Udemy_Selenium_Java ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory F:\Java projects\Udemy_Selenium_Java\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Udemy_Selenium_Java ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 95 source files to F:\Java projects\Udemy_Selenium_Java\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ Udemy_Selenium_Java ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestClass
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hello how are you
????? ????? ????????? ???
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.706 s - in TestClass
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.789 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-23T20:39:23+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Udemy_Selenium_Java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Working screenshot with TestNG:
[TestNG Working Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHnjO.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure encoding in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017695/how-to-configure-encoding-in-maven)

Comment: I do believe that is power shell issue

Comment: Have set sourceEncoding to UTF-8 only

Comment: Character display issues can come from any part of the execution chain: the file itself (the one containing the characters to display), the code reading the file, the code printing the text, some process above that (the JVM), the shell in which it is run, and finally the operating system. Have you tried running the same command with the same files but from different shells or operating systems? If the result is not garbled, you should have a look at your current shell or operating system character encoding/display configuration.

Comment: Code page 1252 is not UTF-8

Comment: Thanks, maxime.bochon. It looks OS encoding issue as it works on diffrent OS lang.